How can i implement javascript Bootstrap 5 tab onChange event in native javascript?
I have a 3 tab. I want an event to be triggered when I click on each tab, but when I apply the code shown in the Bootstrap 5 documentation, it only happens when the first tab triggers events.
Here is the example code that shown on Bootstrap 5 docs.
var tabEl = document.querySelector('button[data-bs-toggle="tab"]')
tabEl.addEventListener('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  console.error(e.target);
  // event.target // newly activated tab
  // event.relatedTarget // previous active tab
})    

I saw that this can be done with jquery, but how can I do it without using jquery ?
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_bootstrap_editor.php
Here is the code for playground.Click tab-2 then click tab-1.
https://jsfiddle.net/eguvenc/pugxj6dm/

Use .querySelectorAll() instead, then loop through the returned list of element and add event listeners to each tab.

Here is the full answer thanks to @Pointy.
var tabEl = document.querySelectorAll('button[data-bs-toggle="tab"]')
tabEl.forEach(function(el){
  el.addEventListener('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    console.error(e.target);
    // event.target // newly activated tab
    // event.relatedTarget // previous active tab
  })    
})

